# how to set the onerror attribute value from css3?

Tags: javascript, css

For my all images I need to set the on error attribute value globally, is there any way to set it from css3 instead of using the js?

Comment: I believe you're talking about [:invalid pseudo-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid), otherwise improve your question.

Answer (score 2):

No, no way, CSS is a presentation language, you have to use a small JS script to do that.

For example :

```
var myImg = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
myImg.setAttribute('onerror', 'INSERT YOUR BEHAVIOUR HERE');
```